# ng-class with function result as condition?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with a conditional ng-class on an element like this:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: checkTemplate()=='html'">
```

the function does some checks and returns an error code. I want to check the returned code and if it's `html`, to add the error class.

However, this generats an error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column NaN of the expression [{error: checkTemplate()=='html'] starting at [{error: checkTemplate()=='html'].
```

What's the problem in here?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `}` at the end of `ng-class`

Try:

```
ng-class="{error : checkTemplate()=='html'}"
```

Comment: there is one " too much

Answer (score 0):

try this

You have added the { , So remove that

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="error: checkTemplate()=='html'">
```